# Check how many times was form submited

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am wondering how can I check is someone tried to log in on site and if he fails login few times to redirect him on forgot password page. I am little word less so I don't know what should I look for. I should try it with jquery and ajax.
I think about something with if password is wrong to echo password is wrong but on third time to send user on forgot page. Now my question is how can I check how many times did someone press submit button with error message for wrong password or username.

Comment: Use a mysql database, create a table to store failed logins based on user and time.

Comment: If the table is keyed on username, it will get wrong counts if he tries different usernames each time. Maybe just use a cookie to count the number of attempts from a particular client computer.

Comment: yeah i saw that  ill do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a cookie or a session variable. You can save the number of tries in it. Then you can redirect, if the number is too high.